# Print a ULONG value with DbgPrint in kernel mode driver

Tags: output, driver

I try to figure out how to print a certain value in a driver. In my case it is a ULONG value. At https://www.osronline.com/showthread.cfm?link=187470, it states that one should use the %U format specifier. So, I have the following code (only the relevant parts):

```
 ULONG value; 

 value = 5;

 DbgPrint("The value is: %U", value);
```

Compiling and loading works fine. But the "DbgView" output is not what I expected as you can see below:

> The value is U

I hope someone can help. Thanks in advance.

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

That is **wrong**

Per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=vs-2017#type-field-characters

To format ULONG, please use:

1. `%u`, for decimal integer.
2. `%x`, for unsigned hexadecimal integer; uses "abcdef."
3. `%X`, for unsigned hexadecimal integer; uses "ABCDEF."